# How to process cedilla delimiter in redshift copy,unload commands inside a stored procedure(Copy delimiter single byte character)?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, dynamic-sql, amazon-redshift-spectrum

My query is like this:

```
unload('select * from table') to 's3://path'
credentials '*******'
header
parallel off
delimiter as '\307'
```

The delimiter is Cedilla Ç. and I have to unload it like this `'\307'`. When I execute the query directly, it works. But when I tried to execute it from redshift stored procedure, `BAD UTF8 hex sequence: C7 27 (error 4)`  is observed.

```
create or replace procedure unload_table(in path varchar)
as 
$$
begin
execute
'unload(''select * from table'') to ''||path||''
    credentials '*******'
    header
    parallel off
    delimiter as ''\307'';';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I tried calling the procedure using

```
call unload_table('s3://path')
```

I had a very long query but I checked each and every issues finally when i replaced the cedilla delimiter '\307' by pipe delimiter '|' , the procedure worked. But, I would need the output file with '\307' delimiter only. Also, I am using redshift `copy` command, before this query with same delimiter, So I had issues there also. So, unloading in '|' delimiter and changing the delimiter later will not be good option here.

Since, it is a dynamic SQL, '\307' is not supported as a string, and when I try to use Ç, directly in a dynamic SQL, i got the error as COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character.

Any way that I can support this delimiter from inside a stored procedure in redshift.

Comment: When I have trouble with interpreting non-ASCII characters in Redshift I fall back to the CHR() function.  As a Redshift function the interpreter in play cannot mis interpret the meaning. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CHR.html  Try CHR(307) instead - there's a good chance it will fix the situation.  But I've never done what you are trying so no promises.

Comment: Since this is in a stored procedure you may need to make this dynamic SQL.

Comment: `CHR(307)` gave differenct value; Since, it is a dynamic SQL, `'\307'` is not supported as a string, and when I try to use `Ç`, directly in a dynamic SQL, i got the error as COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character.

Comment: That is true.  COPY is picky that way.